# Javascript html header strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, reference, header

Consider the following html head javacsript and css referecnes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fadeslideshow.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
     $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat:'DD dd/mm/yy',showAnim: 'slide'});

     $("#anim").change(function(){
          $("#datepicker").datepicker("option","showAnim",$(this).val());
     }); 

});
</script>
```

The above datepicker does not work, but this does:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fadeslideshow.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>   

<script>
$(function(){
     $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat:'DD dd/mm/yy',showAnim: 'slide'});

     $("#anim").change(function(){
          $("#datepicker").datepicker("option","showAnim",$(this).val());
     }); 

});
</script>
```

So if I place the referencve 'fadeslideshow.js' above the the reference to the main jquery library and ui file. Similarliy if I comment out the fadeslideshow.js reference the datepicker will work.

Why would this be the case, it took me over an hour to figure out why the datepciekr was not working?

Thanks,

Alan.

Comment: What is fadeslideshow.js?

Comment: fadeslideshow.js must have a dependency on jquery...that throws an error and your javascript blows up.

Comment: fadeslideshow.js is an external library which i picked up from dynamic drive. I would expect that as long as jquery, and jquery-ui were above any other references all should work?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing exactly what fadeslideshow.js contains, or at least what the error is. Did you open the console and check for errors ?

Comment: I fixed it by dding a reference to an old version of jquery - 1.3.2-min.js. Is it possible that fadeslideshow.js would require an old version and not be compatiable with version 1.9.1?

Comment: Yes it's possible, if you download old crap you sometimes have to use other old crap to make it work.

Comment: It's a legacy website which I'm adding something to so I have to live with the old crap sadly. Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 2):

Because browsers evaluate Javascript files as soon as they are loaded. `fadeslideshow.js` depends on either jQuery or jQuery UI. it will try to reference a non-existant object, which, depending of the functionality of the script, may set a variable to a state not compatible to jQuery UI's datepicker.

Comment: fadeslideshow.js doesn't depend on jquery-ui, only datepicker.js in my exaple does

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding a reference to an old version of jquery which fadeslideshow.js must obviously depend on:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```